# Equivalence relation and numerability of sets

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Be $A$ an infinite numbered set and $R$ equivalent relation . Is defined:

$C(A) = \{R \subseteq A \times\ A | R \} $

Demonstrate $C(A)$ its always not enumerable

problem: why set C is not enumerated? I've tried to start for equivalence relation definition, but I don't see the solution. Equivalency classes is the way to this exercise?

Comment: **Hint:** You should be aware of related problems and results, for instance that the powerset $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$ is uncountable.  Now... ask yourself why I brought that particular result up.  How can you use that result to your advantage for your problem?

Comment: I think it is not clear what is $C(A)$; indeed, from your definition, I don't even have a clue...